# Custom Error Page - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-error-pages

I am trying to setup a custom error page in my website. I am following the guidelines at[PerfectLine Blog](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails).

It works in the case where the controller exists, but the id does not exist. For example, I have a blog controller and id 4 does not exist. It shows the custom error page

But it does not exist in the case, where controller itself does not exist. For example, if I type some random controller with a numeric id does not gets caught by the methods I have setup in the application controller to re-route the custom error pages. In this case, I get an

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/randomcontrollername"):`

in the terminal and the default error page that comes with rails.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception,                            :with => :render_error
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,         :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,       :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController,  :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction,      :with => :render_not_found
  end

  private
  def render_not_found(exception)
     render :template => "/error/404.html.erb", :status => 404
  end

  def render_error(exception)
    render :template => "/error/500.html.erb", :status => 500 
  end

end
```

Could you please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You can do that with route globbing in rails, It lets you match any action to any part of a route using wildcards.

To catch all remaining routes, just define a low priority route mapping as the last route in `config/routes.rb`:

In Rails 3:
`match "*path" => 'error#handle404'`

In Rails 2:
`map.connect "*path", :controller => 'error', :action => 'handle404'`

`params[:path]` will contain the matching part.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need dynamic error pages, just edit `public/404.html` and `public/505.html`. If you do, see Reza.mp's answer.