# Ruby on Rails 3 - 404 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-code-404

I am trying to setup my 404s in rails...

I have followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525715/custom-error-page-ruby-on-rails/4529401#4529401) instructions

and its seems to work if do do something like:

www.myapp.com/no_controller/

but if I do:

www.myapp.com/existing_controller/no_action

I get the Active Record, record not found...etc...

I would like that to also route to the 404 page...is this possible?

Comment: 404 error is some kind of auto route. It will automatically show `public/404.html` page for 404 error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you go to

```
www.myapp.com/existing_controller/no_action
```

you actually call `show` action of `existing_controller` with `no_action` as `id`. In the development mode you get RecordNotFound error. In the production you will get a 404 page.

If you want to customize this behavior in the development mode and root to the 404 page (BTW I don't suggest it! because it was done intentionally to help you debug), you can `rescue_from` this error:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    render_404
  end 

  def render_404
    respond_to do |type|
      type.html { render :template => "shared/error_404/message", :layout => "application", :status => "404 Not Found" }
      type.all  { render :nothing  => true, :status => "404 Not Found" }
    end
  end
end
```

**Out of the scope.** One technique in this example can be useful when designing 404 pages: unlike standard `public/404.html` you can use application layout with this approach.